# What type of field do I need in MySQL to enter song lyrics?

Tags: mysql, field

I have a table with song title, artist, etc. and everything works file. I have a field for lyrics that I want to use to store song lyrics and it is currently set to "blob". If I enter a long text, it always fails. What should I have it set to?

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL        server version for the right syntax to use near 't real, She ain't gonna be able to love you     like I will, She is a stranger, Y' at line 2
```

Nevermind, I figured it out. I need to add mysql_real_escape_string() before enter the text. Correction, it store all empty space. What am I missing?

Example of the lyrics here:

> "Rumour Has It"
>
> Owwwwh [repeats]
>
> She, she ain't real, She ain't gonna be able to love you like I will,
>   She is a stranger, You and I have history, Or don't you remember?
>   Sure, she's got it all, But, baby, is that really what you want?
>
> Bless your soul, you've got your head in the clouds, She made a fool
>   out of you, And, boy, she's bringing you down, She made your heart
>   melt, But you're cold to the core, Now rumour has it she ain't got
>   your love anymore,
>
> Rumour has it (rumour) [x8]
>
> She, is half your age, But I'm guessing that's the reason that you've
>   stayed, I heard you've been missing me, You've been telling people
>   things you shouldn't be, Like when we creep out when she ain't around,
>   Haven't you heard the rumours?
>
> (Bless your soul!...) Bless your soul, you've got your head in the
>   clouds, You made a fool out of me, And, boy, I'm bringing me down, You
>   made my heart melt, yet I'm cold to the core, But rumour has it I'm
>   the one you're leaving her for,
>
> Rumour has it (rumour) [x8]
>
> All of these words whispered in my ear, Tell a story that I cannot
>   bare to hear, Just 'cause I said it, it don't mean that I meant it,
>   People say crazy things, Just 'cause I said it, don't mean that I
>   meant it, Just 'cause you heard it,
>
> Rumour has it (rumour) [x14]
>
> But rumour has it he's the one I'm leaving you for.

Comment: `TEXT` for rock songs, `LONGTEXT` for ballads.

Comment: "If I enter a long text, it always fails" What do you mean by it fails? Is there a specific error?

Comment: I have a PHP form that updates the information. If I enter something simple like Roooooling, it works fine. But if i paste the whole text, it spits out error. The field for lyrics is currently set to "text"

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 't real, She ain't gonna be able to love you like I will, She is a stranger, Y' at line 2

Comment: Try putting the value into a prepared statement, and, do a small test with just two lines.  I expect the problem will come up there also.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at this, to see how long each text type can be:

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/maximum-length-mysql-text-field-types/

But here are the values:

```
TINYTEXT    256 bytes    
TEXT    65,535 bytes            ~64kb
MEDIUMTEXT  16,777,215 bytes    ~16MB
LONGTEXT    4,294,967,295 bytes ~4GB
```

So, why not use `TEXT` instead of `blob`?

Also, it may be that you just have an error in how you are trying to insert or update. Showing some code would be very useful.

Comment: I did have text originally but it didnt work. I guess I can try long text.

Comment: @user1781482: `TEXT` is *more* than enough for the example you posted. It's impossible to guess what your error message was, why don't you just tell us?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that i need to have addslashes() and stripslashes() before I store or output the information. This solved my problem. Thanks!